# Template inside render function is not resolving - LitElement

Tags: javascript, fetch, lit-element

I was trying to get a list through an ajax call but before it gets resolved, **`render()`** method is being called and the template fragment dependent on the Promise was not able to resolve and throws undefined.

**Question**: How to show a loader till I get the data from the Promise?

```
import {
    LitElement,
    html
} from 'lit-element';

class EmpComponent extends LitElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.data = this.getEmpData();
    }

    getEmpData() {
        fetch('../../../emp-data.json')
            .then(
                function(response) {
                    if (response.status !== 200) {
                        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
                            response.status);
                        return;
                    }

                    response.json().then(data => data);
                }
            )
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
            });
    }

    render() {
        <div>
            ${this.data.map(emp => emp.active ? this.dataTemplate(emp) : '')} 
        </div>
    }
}

customElements.define('emp-component', EmpComponent);
```

**Getting this error:**

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**step 1:** create a `js` file that return `true` or `false` (e.g. util.js)

```js
export function when(expression, truVal, falseVal) {
    if (expression) {
        return truVal();
    }
    if (falseVal) {
        return falseVal();
    }
    return undefined;
}
```

**step 2:** import util in your `js` file

```js
import {
    LitElement,
    html
} from 'lit-element';
import {
    when
} from 'util.js'
```

**step 3:** set a `isLoading` property in `static get properties`. So on inital load, we set `onload` to true in `constructor`

```js
import {
    LitElement,
    html
} from 'lit-element';
import {
    when
} from 'util.js'

class EmpComponent extends LitElement {
    static get properties() {
        return {
            isLoading: {
                type: Boolean
            },

        }
    }
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.isLoading = true;
    }
```

**step 4:** once data is fetched, we are ready to render DOM. Then we can set `isLoading` to false and then render DOM using `when`

```js
static get properties() {
    return {
        isLoading: {
            type: Boolean
        },
        canRender: {
            type: Boolean
        }
    }
}
constructor() {
    super();
    this.isLoading = true;
    this.canRender = false;
    this.data = this.getEmpData();
    this.isLoading = false;
    this.canRender = true;
}

render() {
    return html `
    ${when(this.isLoading,() => html`<p>Loading...</p>`)}
    ${when(this.canRender,() => html`<your-component></your-component>`)}
  `
}
```

This is an alternate solution for `until`. you can get more details from this blog [sabarinath blog](https://jsabarinath.wordpress.com/2019/12/26/how-to-make-a-simple-component-using-lit-html-with-api-response/)

Answer (score 1):

You're not returning anything in `getEmpData()` so `this.data` is `undefined`, hence the error.

Keep in mind that if you add a `return` statement before the `fetch()` call `this.data` will then contain a `Promise`. The [`until`](https://lit-html.polymer-project.org/guide/template-reference#until) directive can help in this case:

```js
import {until} from 'lit-html/directives/until.js';

// ...

render() {
  return html`
    <div>
      ${until(
        this.data.then(data => data.map(emp => emp.active ? this.dataTemplate(emp) : ''),
        html`<p>Loading...</p>`,
      )} 
    </div>
  `;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

### The solution

I comment the parts where you should make changes. You don't need to do weird things with other imports

```
import { LitElement, html } from 'lit-element';
    
class EmpComponent extends LitElement
{
    constructor() {
        super();
        // you were returning a promise to an Array type...
        // this.data = this.getEmpData();
        // Correct
        this.data = [];
        this.getEmpData();
    }

    // ADD PROPS
    static get properties() {
        return {
            data: {type:Array}
        };
    }

    getEmpData() {
        fetch('../../../emp-data.json')
            .then(()=>(response) {
                    if (response.status !== 200) {
                        console.log('Looks like there was a problem. Status Code: ' +
                            response.status);
                        return;
                    }
                    // SET DATA ON RESOLVE
                    response.json().then(data => this.data = data);
                }
            )
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log('Fetch Error :-S', err);
            });
    }

    render() {
        <div>
            $ {
                (this.data || []).map(emp => emp.active ? this.dataTemplate(emp) : '')
            } 
        </div>
    }
}

customElements.define('emp-component', EmpComponent);
```